# Connect to Mariadb via sequelpro to a synology NAS

Tags: mysql, mariadb, nas, sequelpro

The goal here is to connect to mariadb via sequelpro, or by ssh.

The problem that I found is related with the application itself. If I get access to synology server via ssh, I can access to mysql server. How? Going to the folder and run:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -uroot -p
```

However, if I try to connect via sequelpro (see screenshot1), it returns an error(see screenshot2). How can I solve this problem? Any idea?

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

Answer (score 3):

Worked out for me with the exact same settings on the admin account, might sounds silly but might worth a try...

[image: screenshot]

Cheers,
Maxime

Answer (score 0):

Using the user "admin" does indeed work. In stead of, in my case, the user "frank" with full admin privileges, this one does not work. I am not at all happy to enable the admin account. Would like to find out if there is an other, more secure way of connecting to MariaDB via SSH using database client software. In my case it is Navicat for MySQL, although the problem seems universal to many clients.